# How to make popup element with position fixed under the second <html> and <body> tags?

Tags: html, css

I have structure:

```
<html>
    <body>
      <iframe>
        #document
        <html>
          <body>
           <div class="popup"></div>
          </body>
       </html> 
   </body>
</html>
```

I made element with class popup with position:fixed; but that's not possible because element belong to the second html and body tag. Withouth these elements it's working fine. How can I solve this?

Comment: You can't have that structure. Are you missing an iframe?

Comment: I have also iframe sorry.

Comment: Fixed positioned elements in an iframe are always positioned relative to the iframe.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I'm testing it's not fixed because with scrolling of the main html and body I cannot put position fixed of this element.

Comment: _Withouth these elements it's working fine. How can I solve this?_ Where's the problem then, delete those two since that's invalid in the first place.

Comment: Because I have structure of page like this and I cannot change it.

Comment: OK, well, then all there is to it is to position the iframe itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible.

A document loaded in an iframe is an independent document.

Elements belonging to that document do not belong to the parent document and cannot appear outside the borders of the iframe.